# SOLVED- Why is response from AES_DECRYPT only displaying ????? characters with mysql db?

Tags: mysql

Im trying to get AES_ENCRYPT/AES_DECRYPT to work with mySql 5.7 to be able to encrypt passwords.
But my response text is only ????

I have a table "personal" and there I have created a column called thepassword, and I have set it to be VARBINARY(256).

I don´t know if the connection/driver to my db has anything to do with it, but here it is.

```
strConn = "driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};server=localhost;uid=xxxx;pwd=xxxx;database=xxxx;option=3" 
set conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Open strConn
```

And it is a asp classic page where I first inserted with this.

```
sql= "INSERT into personal (name, thepassword) VALUES ('Bob',AES_ENCRYPT('testar encrypt texten', 'mypasskey2018'));"
conn.Execute (sql)
```

And this creates a blob in the column thepassword.

And this is how I select it.

```
sql2 = "SELECT AES_DECRYPT(thepassword,'mypasskey2018')  AS passw FROM personal"
set rs2 = conn.Execute (sql2)

do until rs2.eof
    response.write rs2("passw")
rs2.movenext
loop
```

And it displays a lot of "??????????n"

But if I use mySqlWorkBench and run `SELECT AES_DECRYPT(thepassword,'mypasskey2018')  AS passw FROM personal` then it selects and displays the passw column and I can see the right value.

So why am I only getting ??????????n when I try to display it in my .asp page?

Any input really appreciated, thanks.

**SOLVED** - Ok so I solved it finally. I had to use CONVERT USING UTF8 in my select like this. So now it is displaying the value from thepassword column as text.

```
select *,CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(thepassword,'mypasskey2018' ) USING utf8) AS passw from personal
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix the "???"'s to the real text, you may need to change your terminal settings to accept utf-8 (this procedure varies on vim, emacs, and putty).  This will show values, though, like this:

```
select AES_ENCRYPT('testar encrypt texten', 'mypasskey2018');

+-------------------------------------------------------+
| AES_ENCRYPT('testar encrypt texten', 'mypasskey2018') |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
| ▒Xv^▒y▒▒▒▒v▒G▒▒▒▒:▒'▒▒Η▒РG'                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

But to select a readable `VARBINARY` value in MySQL, do not forget to use `HEX()`.  Like this:

```
select HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('testar encrypt texten', 'mypasskey2018'));

+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| HEX(AES_ENCRYPT('testar encrypt texten', 'mypasskey2018'))       |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 05D758765EA5798296E3B5D876A24788A3F606A03A95278CFFCE97ADD0A04727 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Depending on what you're doing, you may not need the `HEX()` at all, but at least with this you will be able to see the precise data that is actually being stored there hexadecimally.

If you're not sure if it's working, then check out a select on a decryption of an encrypted value.  It seems to work to me:

```
select AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('testar encrypt texten', 'mypasskey2018'), 'mypasskey2018');

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT('testar encrypt texten', 'mypasskey2018'), 'mypasskey2018') |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| testar encrypt texten                                                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If you're concerned about having to read and compare hex values, or if you're concerned about converting sensitive data to a readable format, there are some tricks we can do.  For selecting a user account by password, for instance, you would do...

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE User.Password = PASSWORD($user_input);
```

In this sense, if Password is "cool", I don't need to worry about that, or what it hashes or encrypts to.  I can simply select by these means.

Comment: Thanks Hold. Im not sure what you mean with the change in the terminal? I get the ???n when I view the .asp page in the browser. 

When I use the select code from my question in mysqlworkbench I see both the hex value and the text as I should, but when I use it in my .asp page I get the ????n. The column is set to utf8mb4. 

I need to be able to see and write the value as text since I might use this for other than passwords as well for example email addresses. 

Im not sure what the last mypasskey2018 in your code does?

Comment: So if I understand you right, if I just need to see, if a value match then I dont needto use aes_decrypt in the select, only when I need to write it out?

Comment: Ok so it finally works. I had to have CONVERT USING UTF8, like this select *,CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(the password,'mypasskey2018' ) USING utf8) AS passw from personal. But why do I need to convert it? Im using utf8mb4 on my database and in all my files, please see my updated question above.

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson : Hey, glad to see things are better.  UTF-8 issues are entirely new bag of problems, and many answers on it (some are mine).  Did my answer help you with `VARBINARY`-types?  Can you **please** mark it as correct?  UTF-8: Your db, your table, your fields, EACH have their own UTF-8 config; connection string is irrelevant; you'll want to do `SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM YourTable`, and look for `utf8_general_ci` under `Collation`, then check every field's config, encoding, AND collation, etc..  It could be anything.

Comment: Or open a new question!  Keep things nice and sorted, I promise I'll answer it, just post the link here.

Comment: Thanks Hold, I posted a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60589167/why-do-i-need-to-use-convert-using-utf8-with-aes-decrypt-in-select-string

Comment: @ClaesGustavsson : Excellent, taking a look now.