# Why do I need to use CONVERT USING UTF8 with AES_DECRYPT in select string?

Tags: encryption, utf-8

I have tested to use AES_DECRYPT on a .asp page and it only showed ???? instead of the descypted value in clear text, when I used this select query.

```
select *,AES_DECRYPT(thepassword,'myencyptkey2018' ) AS passw from personal
```

But if I use this with **convert using utf8** then it displays the text value.

```
select *,CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(thepassword,'myencyptkey2018' ) USING utf8) AS passw from personal
```

My mySql databas is set to use charset utf8, my .asp uses charset utf8, the connection string as well, as far as I know I'm using utf8 everywhere. So my question is, why do I need to use **convert using utf8**? 
Why isn´t the first select code above work? Where in my settings is it not using utf8? If anywhere?
Thanks.

This is the variables that you might want to see?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your db results from the following commands up above?  `SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME, COLLATION_NAME FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourdb' AND TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable';` `SELECT @@character_set_database;`
`SELECT @@collation_database;` `show variables like 'char%';` `show variables like 'collation%';`

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, I set up a varbinary with proper utf-8 configs, and am able to insert `AES_ENCRYPT()` and select `AES_DECRYPT()` without `CAST` or `CONVERT`, so, I strongly believe it is a config issue.  I'll be able to see it if you run those commands for me.

Comment: Ok greate. Will fix it tomorrow, Im at work all night. Thanks. Yes I guess it is a config issue since I can do it without CAST or CONVERT if I do it directly in mySqlworkbench, but not in the .asp page itself. Will get back tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Hold. Im getting this when I run it. collation_connection utf8_general_ci
collation_database utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_server utf8mb4_unicode_ci